# Is there a reason to not adopt Apex global caching?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

In the Salesforce Summer '22 Release Notes, there is a small section on the new `scope` annotation for `@AuroEnabled` Apex methods:

- [Choose Global Cache Scope for Apex Controller Methods](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_EnhancementToAuraEnabledAnnotation.htm&release=238&type=5)

Under what conditions would you not want to adopt this annotation? When is enabling `global` scope not the appropriate thing to do?

Example from the [dreamhouse-lwc](https://github.com/trailheadapps/dreamhouse-lwc/blob/main/force-app/main/default/classes/PropertyController.cls) sample application:

```apex
public with sharing class PropertyController {
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true scope='global')
  public static PagedResult getPagedPropertyList(String searchKey...) {
    // snip...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if this information was available at the time of asking, but today you can find the answer [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.exp_cloud_perf_apex_caching.htm&type=5).

What it means:

As long as we don't write Apex used in Lightning components used in [LWR](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwr/overview), the global scope doesn't make a difference. I'd opt for the more restrictive and don't use it.

If Apex is called by a component from a LWR context and Salesforce's CDN is used, for speed reasons it's worth asking, if the data is to be publicly available and doesn't get stale. In that specific case declaring a global scope can make sense.